# Retrieve data from a switch case

Tags: javascript, html, api

I start in Javascript, and my mission is to retrieve data from an API.

Today I am a step where I have to filter my data according to the user's requests.

Here I want to retrieve the value of the  html which is then connected to the switch case in JS. And then fetch the URL of the API according to the  value selected by the user.

To make YOU understand, a URL present in the code is equal to a database and I want to select the database to display in my table.

I don't know if I made myself understood. In any case I share my code with you. I've been around my brain, I may have missed something. Any help will be appreciated. Thank's

```
function boutonSubmit(){

bounceType = document.getElementById('BouncesType').value;
datestart = document.getElementById('dateS').value;
dateend = document.getElementById('dateE').value;
//bounceCode = getElementById('#dateS').value;  

var SelectDB = document.getElementById('selectdb').value;

switch(SelectDB){
    case 'Desclopinette':
    `https://api7.esv2.com/v2/Api/Bounces?apiKey=867XXXXXXXXXXXvGN&startDate=${this.datestart}&endDate=${this.dateend}&bounceType=${this.bounceType}`
        break; 
    
    case 'Chrysolum':
    `https://api7.esv2.com/v2/Api/Bounces?apiKey=utxyiwq1K8S04WauVIa0&startDate=${this.datestart}&endDate=${this.dateend}&bounceType=${this.bounceType}`
        break;  
        
    case 'Acanthius':
    `https://api7.esv2.com/v2/Api/Bounces?apiKey=v6PjXXXXXXXXXXX8y682&startDate=${this.datestart}&endDate=${this.dateend}&bounceType=${this.bounceType}`
        break;    

    case 'Bellapourpre':
    `https://api7.esv2.com/v2/Api/Bounces?apiKey=xj530XXXXXXXXXXXRIZlD&startDate=${this.datestart}&endDate=${this.dateend}&bounceType=${this.bounceType}`
        break;  
    
    case 'Alibigratis':
    `https://api7.esv2.com/v2/Api/Bounces?apiKey=SwyXXXXXXXXXXXdKz7z&startDate=${this.datestart}&endDate=${this.dateend}&bounceType=${this.bounceType}`
        break;

    case 'Bullecreatif':
    `https://api7.esv2.com/v2/Api/Bounces?apiKey=CN7XXXXXXXXXXXw30llOD&startDate=${this.datestart}&endDate=${this.dateend}&bounceType=${this.bounceType}`
        break;

    case 'Cacologia':
    `https://api7.esv2.com/v2/Api/Bounces?apiKey=oxjs3XXXXXXXXXXXeGjg&startDate=${this.datestart}&endDate=${this.dateend}&bounceType=${this.bounceType}`
        break;

    case 'Elenaparc':
    `https://api7.esv2.com/v2/Api/Bounces?apiKey=t02ZrrXXXXXXXXXXXoBm1&startDate=${this.datestart}&endDate=${this.dateend}&bounceType=${this.bounceType}`
        break;

    case 'Histoiredepoint':
    `https://api7.esv2.com/v2/Api/Bounces?apiKey=juiHFXXXXXXXXXXXSY68y5V&startDate=${this.datestart}&endDate=${this.dateend}&bounceType=${this.bounceType}`
        break;

    case 'Iatraliptice':
    `https://api7.esv2.com/v2/Api/Bounces?apiKey=LW24pXXXXXXXXXXXTfa28U&startDate=${this.datestart}&endDate=${this.dateend}&bounceType=${this.bounceType}`
        break;

    case 'Maitrechic':
    `https://api7.esv2.com/v2/Api/Bounces?apiKey=ZbpXXXXXXXXXXXy0S&startDate=${this.datestart}&endDate=${this.dateend}&bounceType=${this.bounceType}`
        break;

    case 'Neojaune':
    `https://api7.esv2.com/v2/Api/Bounces?apiKey=TA3XXXXXXXXXXXeBJlvc&startDate=${this.datestart}&endDate=${this.dateend}&bounceType=${this.bounceType}`
        break;

    case 'OreilledeLapin':
    `https://api7.esv2.com/v2/Api/Bounces?apiKey=uqTXXXXXXXXXXXzf0Eg&startDate=${this.datestart}&endDate=${this.dateend}&bounceType=${this.bounceType}`
        break;

    case 'Princecalme':
    `https://api7.esv2.com/v2/Api/Bounces?apiKey=3phXXXXXXXXXXXvO4M4lZ9&startDate=${this.datestart}&endDate=${this.dateend}&bounceType=${this.bounceType}`
        break;
                default:
                    console.log(`Sorry, we are out of ${Selectdb}`)
            
}

        // Is this the right thing to fetch?
        fetch(SelectDB)
            .then((response) => response.text())
            .then((txtResponse) => {
            data = txtResponse;
            console.log(data);
            data = csvJSON(data);
        
            const tbody = document.querySelector('#user-table tbody');
            
            tbody.innerHTML = '';

            

            data.forEach( (user) => {
            const entry = document.createElement('tr')
        
        entry.innerHTML = `

            <tr>
                <td class="column1">${user.Date}</td>
                <td class="column2">${user.Email}</td>
                <td class="column3">${user.BounceCode}</td>
                <td class="column3">${user.BounceType}</td>
            </tr>
            `;
          
            tbody.appendChild(entry);
                });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you better replace switch case with something more suitable for your case. You can exclude base API URL in constant variable

```
const DATABASE_API = 'https://api7.esv2.com/v2/Api'
```

then it makes sence to create separate key=value object with apiKeys

```
const DB_API_KEYS = {
    Desclopinette: 'v6PjXXXXXXXXXXX8y682',
    Chrysolum: 'utxyiwq1K8S04WauVIa0',
    // and so on...
}
```

after that you're good to go with full url constructing

```
const dbApiKey = DB_API_KEYS[SelectDB]

if (dbApiKey === undefined) {
    console.log(`Sorry, we are out of ${Selectdb}`)
    // throw or something
}

const url = `${DATABASE_API}/Bounces?apiKey=${dbApiKey}&startDate=${this.datestart}&endDate=${this.dateend}&bounceType=${this.bounceType}`
```

and finally

```
fetch(url)
```